# Splitting up a million-dollar fortune into ten equal piles

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> At his death, a millionaire left his 10 children a million dollars in cash, all in $\$100$, $\$10$, $\$1$ bills and $10$-cent and $1$-cent coins.  Show that there is a way for them to split the fortune into ten stacks of equal value. (Note that this would not be true if there were $3 bills.)

I'm struggling with how to get started. The assignment is on elementary set theory and functions, so there must be some way to apply these concepts, but I'm not sure how. The only thing that came to mind was inclusion-exclusion.

I would appreciate a hint on how to get started. I'll work on it more and edit this post with an updated attempt, but I'd really like to try to figure it out myself.

Comment: The key is that every amount is 10x the next. The number of 1 cent coins must be a multiple of 10 (see if you can figure out why). Therefore, you can combine them into a whole number of "virtual" 10 cents coins by splitting into piles of 10 1 cent coins. Your count of 10 coins (real + virtual) must now be a multiple of 10. Extrapolating, you can eventually have only 100$ and virtual 100$ piles. At that point, there are exactly 10,000 piles, so give each child 1000. To be rigorous, don't use the idea of virtual coin, but instead treat it as sets (have a set of 10 1 cent = 1 ten cent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem apperead as an optional review/warm-up assignment (not due) in [MATH 55A](https://canvas.harvard.edu/courses/75936/assignments/syllabus#hw).  The course provides a rigorous introduction to abstract algebra and I guess that the problem has been chosen as an *unusual* example of proof by induction.

We show a more general statement (for your case assume that 1 unit is equal to 1-cent coin).

> Given an amount of money of $10^{n}$ in $10^{n-1},\dots, 1$ units
> then there is a way to split it into $10$ stacks of equal value.

The proof is by induction on $n\geq 1$. The base step with $n=1$ is trivial: $1\cdot 10=10$ which means that each stack is of $1$ unit.

Inductive step: we assume that $n>1$ and
$$10^{n-1}b_{n-1}+\dots +10b_1+1b_0=10^n$$
where each $b_k$ is a non negative integer. By considering the equality modulo 10 we find that $b_0$ is a multiple of $10$. Then
$$10^{n-1}b_{n-1}+\dots +100b_2+10\left(b_1+\frac{b_0}{10}\right)=10^n$$
that is, after dividing both sides by 10,
$$10^{n-2}b_{n-1}+\dots +10b_2+\underbrace{\big(b_1+\frac{b_0}{10}\big)}_{\text{non-negative integer}}=10^{n-1}$$
and by the induction induction hypothesis we can divide $10^{n-1}$ into $10$ stacks of equal value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Your proof makes sense to me, but is there a way to work in that 10-cent and 1-cent coins are also allowed? I worry that not including them sacrifices generality.

Comment: @BradG. The unit in my proof is not specified,  it suffices to assume that 1 unit of my statement is equal to 1-cent coin

Comment: That helps a lot. The only other question I have: is there a reason you assumed the result inductively for $n > 1$? Does the same proof work if we just assume it for $n \geq 1$?

Comment: @BradG. The inductive step is $P(n-1)\implies P(n)$ for $n>1$. For $n=1$ we have the base step.

Comment: Ok, but didn't you start with the $10^n$ (the $n$ step) and derivative the $10^{n-1}$ step (the $n-1$ step)? This is what I don't fully understand. Wouldn't you want to split up $10^{n+1}$ in the inductive step?

Comment: @BradG. No, in my proof by the induction  hypothesis if we are able to split $10^{n-1}$ (last line) then we can split also $10^n$ (first line).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this approach uses set theory. Anyway this is the approach I found most natural. I give it as a hint.

**Hint**: order the money by value in decreasing order. First 100\$,10\$,1\$,0.1\$, and 0.01\$. Than start taking all banknotes with highest value to build the first heap. Show that you arrive exactly to 100 000\$ taking one by one the banknotes with highest value and therefore build the first heap. Then show that you can continue like that building all remaining nine heaps as well.

It is also instructive trying to generalize (e.g. does it work if we have just banknotes of 20 and 10 dollars?).